# MS SQL Сжатие бэкапа

Tags: sql-server, резервное-копирование

В SSMS есть возможность сжать бэкап при его выполнении.

> Task - Backup - Backup options - Set backup compression

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему сжатие не установлено по умолчанию? Это связано только с повышенным расходом ресурсов процессора на выполнение этой операции? Какой алгоритм сжатия используется? Насколько он эффективен?

Как установить режим сжатия по умолчанию кроме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Почему сжатие не установлено по умолчанию?* Скорость восстановления при сбое дороже расходуемого на бэкап дискового пространства. Опять же - чем больше этапов, тем вероятнее ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установить режим сжатия по-умолчанию:

```
USE master;
GO
EXEC sp_configure ‘backup compression default’, '1';
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
```